# SilverStripe GraphQL many_many Query Fails In Production

Tags: graphql, silverstripe, silverstripe-4

If anyone could help me I’d be so grateful.

When I have my SilverStripe app running locally I can query many_many relationships with GraphiQL. But after I deploy my app on Heroku and run the exact same query with Postman against my deployed API I do not get the many_many data back. (I however still get the main data.) Does anyone know why this happens?

Here are some screenshots, and my source code [here](https://github.com/Dawid-Dahl/stereo-nightclub-graphql/tree/main/app).

[image]
[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If anyone else has this problem in the future, it was solved like this:

[image]